# How to replay animation triggered by adding a class with a transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I make the following script trigger the "open" animation each time a new item is selected?

```js
$('#things div').on('click',function() {
  var val = $(this).html();
  $('#panel').removeClass('open').addClass('open');
  $('#content').html(val);
});

$('#panel').on('click',function() {
  $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .25s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  top: -51px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#content {
  font-size: 30px;
}
#panel.open {
  top: 0;
}

#things div {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel"><div id="content"></div><div>(click to close)</div></div>

<div id="things">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the class and add it again.

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: Can you show a working example that demonstrates that it doesn't work?

Comment: You need to add a delay. Either using `.delay()` or `setTimeout`. Also initially you don't want the delay: `if (hasclass) { remove_class; delay; set_class } else { set_class }`

Comment: Please post as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a delay so the animation can run.

Here I've added a delay of .25s, which is how long your animation is.

So remove the class

```
$('#panel').removeClass('open');
```

Then wait 250 miliseconds and add it again

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#panel').addClass('open')}, 250);
```

Snippet:

```js
$('#things div').on('click',function() {
  var val = $(this).html();
  $('#panel').removeClass('open');
  setTimeout(function(){$('#panel').addClass('open')}, 250);
  $('#content').html(val);
});

$('#panel').on('click',function() {
  $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  top: -51px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#content {
  font-size: 30px;
}
#panel.open {
  top: 0;
  transition: .25s ease-in;
}

#things div {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel"><div id="content"></div><div>(click to close)</div></div>

<div id="things">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks.  Is there any way to remove the transition on the `removeClass()`? Or would that require replacing CSS transitions with jquery `.animate()`?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to do it by changing the transition on `#panel` to `0s` and adding a transition of `.25s` to `.open`.

Comment: @RatherNotsay I did it slightly differently, see my updated answer

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I had in mind. I like the easing touch too. :)

Comment: @RatherNotsay The problem with this is you get the delay every time

Comment: I set the delay to 100ms and it seems completely acceptable to me from a UX perspective.  I actually really like it within the context of my current UI.

Comment: @RatherNotsay Of course, it is your choice, though I posted one that does not do that

Comment: @CalvT see my comment fixes that

Answer (score 1):

You should use a delay so the remove and add class will be ok.

```js
$('#things div').on('click',function() {
  var delay = 500;
  var val = $(this).html();
  
  // for init
  if ( !$('#panel').hasClass('open') ) {
    delay = 0;
  }
    
  $('#panel').removeClass('open');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#content').html(val);
    $('#panel').addClass('open');
  }, delay);
  
});

$('#panel').on('click',function() {
  $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .25s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  top: -51px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#content {
  font-size: 30px;
}
#panel.open {
  top: 0;
}

#things div {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel"><div id="content"></div><div>(click to close)</div></div>

<div id="things">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you add a delay before calling it again.

Here I also check if it has the class, so the timeout only run when it does.

```js
$('#things div').on('click',function() {
  var val = $(this).html();
  if ($("#panel").hasClass("open")) {
    $('#panel').removeClass('open');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#panel').addClass('open');
    }, 250)
    $('#content').html(val);
    return;
  }
  $('#panel').addClass('open');
  $('#content').html(val);
});

$('#panel').on('click',function() {
  $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .25s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  top: -51px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#content {
  font-size: 30px;
}
#panel.open {
  top: 0;
}

#things div {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel"><div id="content"></div><div>(click to close)</div></div>

<div id="things">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you put the         `$('#content').html(val);` in the timeout instead - it will work the expected way - otherwise the content doesnt get updated

Comment: @JFit Missded that...fixed